# using bitwise operation to extract month from int date (yyyyMMdd)

Tags: c#, c++, c, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to extract the month from date represented as `int` (format YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20110401) using some bitwise operators?

If so, how can it be done?

edit:
I am currently using 20110401 % 10000 / 100. I thought bit-wise could be faster. DateTime.Parse etc. are too slow for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Although you can do it with bitwise operations, it's easier to use math operations for this.

Comment: The only two possible answers are "Yes" or "No". Is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: Why is it necessary to use bitwise operations? That seems overly complicated and unnecessary for what you are trying to access. You also seem to list three different language tags, what language are you using? C#, for instance, has built in methods for this.

Comment: The answer is *Yes*, although not straightforward. All arithmetic operations can be implemented through bitwise operations.

Comment: I am currently using 20110401 % 10000 / 100. thought bit-wise could be faster. no?

Comment: "no?" No, not by a long shot, because those divide and mod operations are done by the CPU with bitwise operations at the circuit level.

Comment: However, there is another approach ... see my answer below.

Comment: The is a reasonable question and does not deserve to be downrated. Most of the responses show lack of imagination and a failure to appreciate that this may be a case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Packing data structures usually result in slower code; because you have to spend time packing and unpacking rather than just storing. Is packing necessary? Does packing save a significant amount of memory? Does the difference, between packing and not, make a noticeable improvement on transmission durations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could efficiently extract the month with bitwise operations if you *represented* the date in a binary format, e.g., 5 bits for the day of the month, 4 bits for the month number, and the rest for the year, rather than as decimal digits. For your example, the date would be (2011 << 9) + (4 << 5) + 1 (which of course is not equal to 20110401). To use bitwise operations to extract the fields from such a representation:

```
int year = date >> 9;
int month = (date >> 5) & 0xF;
int day = date & 0x1F;
```

Another approach, as mentioned by Mark Byers, is to use  a struct, e.g.,

```
typedef struct {
    short year;
    char  month;
    char  day;
} Date;
```

You can pass these around on the stack, extract the fields by name, and initialize them as

```
Date d = { 2011, 4, 1};
```

or, in C99,

```
Date d = { .year = 2011, .month = 4, .day = 1 };
```

Answer (score 8):

No, because bitwise operators work with the *binary* representation of the number. Your date is encoded using a *decimal* representation.

You can do it using arithmetic operators though:

```
int date = 20110401;

int day = date % 100;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int year = date / 10000;
```

Comment: Or parse to `DateTime` if using C# ;)

Comment: Of course it is possible, since the computer is doing bitwise operations at the circuit level, but its pointless to try to emulate those in software.

Comment: "Your date is encoded using a decimal representation." -- But does it need to be? See my answer below.

Comment: Or you could use a struct containing a short and two bytes.

Comment: One could, but encoding the date in an int is probably a little easier.

Comment: Or maybe not. I've added your idea to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`20110301` (base 10) as an integer will be represented quite differently at the bit-level, in fact as `1001100101101101111011101` (base 2). Using bit level operations to extract the month from this bit-string is not going to be straight forward.

Alternatives:

- Do some basic math involving mod on the integer
- Convert the `int` into a string and then extract the relevant digits and convert them back to integers.
- Or better yet, to use some already tested library functions for this.

Bit level operations are not a good approach for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using bitwise operations would probably be error prone, if you could do it at all. You can do it by manipulating the number with division and modulo operations.

You could also convert it to a string, parse the the month characters, and then convert back to an int.

Here's some example code in C#

```
int date = 20119420;
int month = 0;

// using good old math
month = (date / 100) % 100;

// using string parsing
month = int.Parse(date.ToString().Substring(4, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an extremely old post but this was actually an assignment for our class, I have a compress date and an extract date function using only bitwise operations:

```
    //Compress Date
    int compressDate(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        int date = year;
        date <<= 4;
        date |= month;
        date <<= 6;
        date |= day;

        return date;

    }

    //Extract Date
    void extractDate(int date, int& month, int& day, int& year)
    {
        int dayMask = 63;
        int monthMask = 15;
        int yearMask = 4095;


        day = date & dayMask;
        date >>= 6;
        month = date & monthMask;
        date >>= 4;
        year = date & yearMask;
    }
```

When you execute the compress date function with something like compressDate(1, 25, 2019), it returns the number: 2067545 and the extractDate function just works in the opposite order. The reason for doing this is that bitwise operators are faster than using math operators.