# parse armydate long number to LocalDate

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

I have a long number in the format:
`Long l = 20151228;`

And I want to parse it into LocalDate object.

How can I do that?

Comment: Using which: Java 8 LocalDate or Joda's LocalDate? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `java.time`, you can break up the number into its respective parts and use the static method `LocalDate.of` to build a local date from them.

```
long militaryDate = 20151228L;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of((int) (militaryDate / 10000),
                            Month.of((int) (militaryDate / 100) % 100),
                            (int) (militaryDate % 100));

System.out.println(ld);
```

Result:

```
2015-12-28
```

Comment: This answer is similar to the one provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11023759/44523 and in my opinion at least the most sensible one as it's just about as efficient as this can be. The only improvement to this is that you'll get rid of casts if `militaryDate`'s type is changed to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is converting the `long` to a `String` and parsing it using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
long l = 20151228L;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date d = df.parse(String.valueOf(l));
```

Comment: But that's neither java.time nor Joda-time and the result is not a `LocalDate` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( df.format(df.parse(String.valueOf(l)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `LocalDate::parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)` which looks like this:

```
Long l = 20151228L;
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(Long.toString(l), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
System.out.println(date);
```

Result:

> 2015-12-28

Answer (score 0):

I prefer RealSkeptic's answer as it is the most efficient one, but if you are not comfortable with modulo arithmetic, I offer you an alternative.

The integer format you are using for the date is actually the BASIC_ISO_DATE format. Therefore, you could use the existing java.time formatter for this:

```
int dateAsInt = 20151228;  // btw no need to use long as it fits easily in an int
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(Integer.toString(dateAsInt), DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
System.out.println(date);
```